# How to get classification report (F1 score) when using keras ImageDataGenerator - AttributeError: 'DirectoryIterator' object has no attribute 'argmax'

Tags: python, keras

Since I do not have the training set and label separated when using Keras ImageDataGenerator but rather I rely on the folder structure. How can I get the classification report, i.e. how can I get/calculate the Precision, Recall, and F1?

This is what I have tried and I get the error that is complaining that the train_generator has not argmax. How can I solve this?

> AttributeError: 'DirectoryIterator' object has no attribute 'argmax'

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1. / 255,
)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_dir, 
    target_size=(150, 150),  
)

predIdxs = model.predict(train_generator)

predIdxs = np.argmax(predIdxs, axis=1)

print(classification_report(train_generator.argmax(axis=1), predIdxs,
                            target_names=["class 1", "class 2"]))
```

Comment: `train_generator.argmax(axis=1)` doesn't work, because `train_generator` is a generator, not a numpy array. You need to load your ground-truth labels and then call `classification_report` with them

Comment: @GPhilo thanks for the tip! Yes, I did that. Posted the answer. Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

This solution worked for me since if you use `flow_from_directory` then you must use `predict_generator` method on model and speaking about `sklearn.metrics.classification_report` ,`ytrue` and `ypred` should be `1-d numpy` array hence used `train_generator.labels`

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1. / 255,
)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_dir, 
    target_size=(150, 150), shuffle = False,   # Must
)

predIdxs = model.predict_generator(train_generator)

predIdxs = np.argmax(predIdxs, axis=1)

print(classification_report(train_generator.labels, predIdxs,
                            target_names=["class 1", "class 2"]))
```